# Trying to read a text file (.txt) and display the text on the text file in a onclick button modal dialog box

Tags: javascript, html, css, node.js

I'm trying to create a modal that displays when the user clicks on the button. That modal should display the text from a different text file on the server. Trying to display text from the text file in a modal dialog box.

I tried linking the file, but the text on the file would not display on the modal. Also tried data-binding with text observable, but not as familiar with it.

```
<div class="logs">
     <button type="button" id="btn2" data-toggle="modal" 
    data-target="#openLog" data-bind="click: GetLog">Whoosh</button>
</div>
<!--n--> 
 <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
   <!-- The Modal -->
 <div id="repModal" class="modal2">

 <!-- Modal content -->
 <div class="repmodal-content">

 <div class="repmodal-header">
 <h2 style="color:white;">Whoosh<style></style></h2>
 </div>
 <div class="remodal-headercontent"></div>
 <div class="repmodal-body" id="logText">
   <span data-bind="text: observable"></span>
   <span class="repclose">Close</span>
</div>
</div>

</div>


<!--Javascript--> 

<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("repModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("btn2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("repclose")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}

</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do that with an XMLHttpRequest

(more info on XMLHttpRequest here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest)

Here is a working example of that:

```js
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("repModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("btn2");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("repclose")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
  let url = "https://baconipsum.com/api/?type=meat-and-filler&format=html";
  var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4){
      if (request.status == 200){
        document.getElementById("modal_text").innerHTML = request.responseText;
      } else {
        //handle error
      }
    }
    
  };
  
  request.open('GET', url);
  request.send();
  
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it

window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="logs">
     <button type="button" id="btn2" data-toggle="modal" 
    data-target="#openLog" data-bind="click: GetLog">Whoosh</button>
</div>
<!--n--> 
 <!-- Trigger/Open The Modal -->
   <!-- The Modal -->
 <div id="repModal" class="modal2">

 <!-- Modal content -->
 <div class="repmodal-content">

 <div class="repmodal-header">
 <h2 style="color:white;">Whoosh<style></style></h2>
 </div>
 <div class="remodal-headercontent"></div>
 <div class="repmodal-body" id="logText">
   <span data-bind="text: observable" id="modal_text"></span>
   <span class="repclose">Close</span>
</div>
</div>

</div>


<!--Javascript-->
```

Comment: when I change the url to the path of the file in the server. It does display the text in the file. I tried replacing it with the file name "notes.txt" and the full path of the file, but still no luck.

Comment: Well, my snippet works, so the problem probably lies in the path of your file. Are you sure you used the right path?

Comment: yeah your snippet works for me as well, and yes I did use the right path. I will try to figure it out. Thanks for your help! The only different thing I'm doing is instead of putting an actual html link, I'm putting the path or the file name. I don't know if that makes any difference.

Comment: You mean you are putting the path of the filename like: C:\Users\User\Docuements\whatever.txt ? Becouse it doesn't work like that.

Comment: Also if you open the site as an html document with a file:/// url, than it is going to give a CORS error

Comment: Yeah, I was doing that. But now that I think of it, I think I have to make a webpage with the text file and then copy that link and post it.

Comment: If you find my answer helpful, you could accept it ;)

Comment: It actually worked, but now it doesn't show just the text on the page, it shows all the code that was written on the page as well. Do you know the solution to this?

Comment: If you want html in the modal as well, not only text, you have to use innerHTML instead of innerText

Answer (score 0):

You can get the text content with an [`XMLHttpRequest`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest).

```
document.getElementById("btn2").addEventListener('click', () => {
    let request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (request.readyState == XMLHttpRequest.DONE) {
            if (request.status == 200) {
                // When the request succeeds, add the response text to the modal.
                let text = document.create("div");
                text.innerHTML = request.responseText;
                modal.appendChild(text);
            } else {
                // You should come up with a graceful solution for if the
                // request fails
            }
        }
    };
    request.open("GET", URL_OF_TEXT_FILE, true);
    request.send();
}, false);
```

edit: You can connect this to the button using `addEventListener()`.

Comment: how would I link this to the button I created?